# Названия отправителя в письме на PHP

Tags: php

Господа, есть в php функция отправка письма на e-mail. Есть там кому, тема, текст, кодировка... Полно всего. Но немогу найти одну вещь - "названия" отправителя.

Вот грубо говоря, если зайти в список писем в яндексе, то там в первой колонке как раз отображаются эти самые "названия". Если зайти в само письмо, то эти "названия" находятся как раз под темой. Подскажите команду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mail("nobody@example.com", // кому
 "the subject", 
  $message,
 "From: webmaster@$SERVER_NAME\r\n" // от кого
."Reply-To: webmaster@$SERVER_NAME\r\n"
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

еще хорошо бы с русским подружиться,

> названия отправителя в письме

проще же написать "от кого"